# Searching open source (possibly) to perform multivariate limit

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, multiple-integral

I'm searching same open source software to perform this kind of limit (without restricting and executing the limit to a variable):

$$
\lim_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)}\frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}
$$
I've seen sage and maxima, but i don't know if they can help me...
Then, if not this, can they perform double and triple integrals?

Comment: This limit not exist.

Answer (score 3):

The limit does not exist since:

$\textbf{Case 1:}$ Let $(x,y) = (x, x^3)$ then we have:
$$\lim_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)}\frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}=\lim_{(x, x^3)\to(0, 0)}\frac{x^6}{x^6+x^6}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$\textbf{Case 2:}$ Let $(x,y) = (x, 0)$ then we have:
$$\lim_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)}\frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}=\lim_{(x, 0)\to(0, 0)}\frac{x^3 \cdot 0}{x^6}=0$$

Comment: Thanks for solving the limit, but i am looking for a software to solve them ..

Comment: @Teo7 In SageMath you can do: `f(x,y) = x^3*y/(x^6 + y^2)` and `f.limit(y=x^3).limit(x=0)` and get `(x, y) |--> 1/2`, but this is a bit of guessing. See this [issue](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/9849) for some details.

Comment: The last update to the post was 7 years ago, since then they haven't added any functions to calculate the multi-variable limits correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Not an open-source solution, but check this: [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit[(x^3 y)/(x^6 + y^2), {x -> 0, y -> 0}]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B%28x%5E3+y%29%2F%28x%5E6+%2B+y%5E2%29%2C+%7Bx+-%3E+0%2C+y+-%3E+0%7D%5D)

Answer (score 2):

Not open source, but instead of WolframAlpha, I prefer Mathematica Online, you can sign up for free: https://www.wolframcloud.com/

Once in, write down

```
Limit[(x^3 y)/(x^6 + y^2), {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
```

and the answer is

```
Indeterminate
```